# GAE datastore (save object)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, nosql, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am new at GAE Api.

At the moment I use  : **com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService** in order to save something in database.

At the moment I need to save list of items in database. should I use JDO ? Or can I do this without it? :-)

I need to save Array in datastore. but I can't do something like that:

```
entity = new Entity(key);
entity.setProperty("uid", arrayObject);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, I suggest you to use [Objectify](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/) for Datastore Operations. You save a lot of time wrapping datastore entities in java objects:

For your question, Array type is not supported by GAE Datastore. Here a [list](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Properties_and_value_types) of supported type. If you need to save an array of items, you have to use a List object